# javascript object contains divs with custom 'data' but I can't view data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code snippet:

```
$(window).load(function() {

  run($('.stickable'));
})

var run = function (headers){
  var $window = $(window)
  var $headers

  $headers = headers.each(function(){
    var $currentHeader = $(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap">');
    $currentHeader
      .data('startPosition', $currentHeader.offset().top)
      .data('headerHeight', $currentHeader.outerHeight())
        .parent()
        .height($currentHeader.outerHeight())
        .width($currentHeader.outerWidth())
  });
}
```

When I place a debugger and console $headers I get what looks like an array of divs. However typeof shows this is an object. When I try $headers.data() I get the startPosition and headerHeight of first div. When I try $headers[2] I get the second div. When I try $headers[2].data() I get an error. When I do a $.each loop I get the correct info. My question is why can't I state $headers[2].data(), or simply select any div and show it's data?

Comment: Don't forget to click the green **✔**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because accessing a jQuery object by index returns a DOMElement, not another jQuery object, hence the `data()` method doesn't exist. Use `eq()` to get a jQuery object by index:

```
var data = $headers.eq(1).data(); // zero-based index, 2nd item = index 1
```